# Excel powerpivot data drill down using filtered data

Tags: excel, powerpivot, drilldown

I created a powerpivot data model for current sales orders. I have 6 columns at the end of the dataset that indicate an attribute of the order (example - if the order has a ship date, I have a 1 in the SHIPPED column). I created a pivot table that summarizes orders by attribute, and the numbers look correct, but when I drill into any of the cells, I would like to only see records with the attribute flag I assigned. So, if I am summarizing shipped orders, I only want to see lines with a 1 in the SHIPPED column. But the drill down returns all lines. Does anyone know if there is a function to exclude rows with certain criteria from the drill down results? I tried CALCULATE with a filter of [table].SHIPPED=1, but that didn't exclude lines without 1. It just summed the lines with 1.